# how to use forever with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

i am trying to run this command in my debian 10 vps `forever start npm start` but i got this error in the terminal,

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: npm
(node:23858) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:23858) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /root/node_projects/tiktok/backend/npm does not exist.
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "auth-graphql",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.11.0"
  },  
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "node -r esm ./src/index.js",
    "start": "nodemon -r esm ./src/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "esm": "^3.2.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  }
}
```

i tried

```
forever start  esm ./src/index.js

forever start -c "npm start" ./

forever start -c "npm start" /path/dir/

forever --sourceDir /path/dir/ -c "npm start" /
```

and i also got almost the same error, Please I need help, How can i solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

try this command:

```
forever start -c "npm start" ./
```

running your application's specific directory:

```
forever start -c "npm start" /path/dir/
```

or use this command:

```
forever --sourceDir /path/dir/ -c "npm start" /
```

Comment: you can set this argument to your command, you want to explicitly set them:           forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 -c "npm start" ./

Comment: i got the same error with this command `forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 -c "npm start" ./`

Comment: i got this error `warn: --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms warn: --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms info: Forever processing file: ./src (node:24326) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency (Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created) (node:24326) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency `

Comment: or try node 6 or 8 version

Comment: it's a warning, I don't think it prevent application from starting, but you have this error: script /root/node_projects/tiktok/backend/npm does not exist => i think your directory maybe wrong

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems and I think it may be some sort of incompatibility with NPM/Node versions (see [discussion here](https://github.com/foreversd/forever/issues/1077).

I switched to https://github.com/Unitech/pm2 instead and things started working immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution but. The problem is related to a circular dependency. Node version 14+ is no longer supports circular dependency. Example
In fileA

```
var fileB = require(fileB);
```

In fileB

```
var fileA = require(fileA);
```